# How to find the ecc named curve used for signature in a SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, elliptic-curve

How to find which ecc named curved is used for generating the signature in SSL certificate. I have checked the Signature field in SSL certificate but it does not indicate the curved used while generating the signature.

Comment: It's not in the child cert, it's (only) in the parameters part of the SubjectPublicKeyInfo in the _parent_ cert (which is used and needed to verify). Although the signature does give you the bit-size and there are only a few standard curves for each size. In practice it's usually NIST P-256 P-384 or P-521, which are easily distinguished by size.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Not sure if this is the right site for this question, but it smells like an answer to me. Without the parent there cert there isn't all that much use for the signature algorithm. For self-signed certs you can of course look in the SubjectPublicKeyInfo of the *current* certificate as it basically is its own parent.